# Hive selectExpression : ( expression | tableAllColumns );])

Tags: java, shell, hadoop

I am trying by Shell Script to create view. 
But it is show the error below;

*"FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Unable to alter table. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from a null string"*

I tested in HUE and works fine. but with shell script does not work.
Find below the Create View.

hive -e "Create or Replace view RAW_ENODEBFUNCTION_VW AS Select substr(p.hbase_key,1, instr(p.hbase_key, '|' )-1 ) neun, SUBSTR(SUBSTR(p.hbase_key,INSTR(p.hbase_key,'|')+1),1,INSTR(SUBSTR(p.hbase_key, INSTR(p.hbase_key,'|')+1),'|')-1)   MTS, reverse(Substr(reverse(p.hbase_key),1, INSTR(reverse(p.hbase_key),'|')-1)) mo, p.pmLicConnectedUsersLevSamp as PMLICCONNECTEDUSERSLEVSAMP, p.pmLicConnectedUsersLevSum as PMLICCONNECTEDUSERSLEVSUM, p.pmLicConnectedUsersMax as PMLICCONNECTEDUSERSMAX From RAW_ENODEBFUNCTION P where p.hbase_key >= 'S01RJABV03|20180615010000|900|ManagedElement=S01RJABV03,ENodeBFunction=1' AND p.hbase_key <= 'S03SMSAMIL|20180615014500|900|ManagedElement=S03SMSAMIL,Transport=1,VlanPort=S1'"
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.12.1-1.cdh5.12.1.p0.3/jars/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.12.1.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Unable to alter table. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from a null string
WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation.